How to ask password after resume
I have Arch Linux with the following partitions:

unencrypted swap partition
unencrypted root partition, mounted as /
encrypted EFI partition, mounted as /boot/efi.  It contains the refind boot manager.
encrypted home partition (using LUCKS), mounted as /home

When booting with no resume it asks for the password for the home partition.
When resuming from hibernation, it doesn't ask for any password.
Which setup do you recommend?
I'm not paranoic on security.  I only try to have a minimal security setup, without compromising too much confortability.
Maybe encrypted swap.
But I think I'll be asked twice for the password if I do so on normal booting.  Normally I resume.
Can I change to encrypted swap without reinstalling everything, by just changing some config files?
